# while creating a dynamic url for user blogs i need to specify the users for the availability of url's that they can create?

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, curl

May i know how to check the dynamic url availability for the user within the domain, so that they are allowed to create their own site-url's

Steps that I am following:
1) Through text box they will be able to write their nickname/personal_identity eg: say Custom_Blog

2) So, my website domain would be http://example.com/Custom_Blog/ for the specified user.

3)Conflict: But I do have a tab "http://example.com/Custom_Blog" link created in the htaccess which is used for editing the Blog detailed page of the user.

So, while user entering in the text box i need to validate the availability of the url whether the url is already in use or not ?
I tried this code which was not helpful because it was getting the code 302 for the url's that are already used(exists):

```
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

/* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
$response = curl_exec($handle);

/* Check for 404 (file not found). */
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpCode == 404 || $httpCode == 302) {
    /* Handle 404 here. */
}

curl_close($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax for the validation

onchange on that input field make request to the php file

in php file send the response about availability.

```
var dataString = {'url':value};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "somefile.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
    // do some stuff here
    }
```

in php file get the url and check it